# Integrating Apple, Google, and Instagram (Meta) Sign-In for Social Media Registration/Login and User Data Handling

Tags: react-native, authentication, google-signin, facebook-login, apple-login

I'm currently working on implementing social media registration and login functionality for my application, and I would like to offer users the option to sign in using Apple, Google, and Instagram (Meta) accounts. However, I'm unsure about how to manage and combine these different sign-in methods seamlessly.

Integration Challenges:
How can I integrate Apple, Google, and Instagram (Meta) sign-ins into my application?
Are there any specific SDKs or APIs that I should be using for each platform?

User Data Handling:
What are the common data fields that I can expect to receive from Apple, Google, and Instagram (Meta) after a successful sign-in?
How can I standardize and combine this data to create a unified user profile within my application?

Username Creation:
I'm interested in using the data obtained from social media sign-ins to automatically generate a username for the user. Are there any best practices or considerations for creating usernames based on the data received from these platforms?

Security Considerations:
What security measures should I implement to ensure the safe handling of user data obtained from these social media platforms?

How do i store login data in SQL db. Should i store every Social Media login way per user?

Any guidance, code snippets, or best practices related to these issues would be greatly appreciated. I want to ensure a smooth and secure user experience while integrating multiple social media sign-in options. Thanks in advance!

Data Inconsistency:
The data structures returned from Apple, Google, and Instagram (Meta) appear to be inconsistent. For instance, certain fields that I expected to be present are missing, and the naming conventions for similar data points differ.

Missing Information:
It seems that certain platforms provide unique user information that is not available in others. This discrepancy makes it challenging to create a standardized user profile.